# display datatable after filtering rows from dropdown list in dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm new to Dash. I would like to make a app, where I can select values from dropdown filter, filter dataset and display the data table. I'm using dash_table.

My example app code is below. No datatable is shown. Does anyone know what I did wrong? How can I render dash table in dash app?

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_table as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)



states = df.State.unique().tolist()

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
    dcc.Dropdown(
            id='filter_dropdown',
            options=[{'label':st, 'value':st} for st in states],
            value = states[0]
            ),
    dt.DataTable(id='table-container') ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output('table-container', 'data'),
    [Input('filter_dropdown', 'value') ] )
def display_table(state):
    dff = df[df.State==state]
    return dff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

BTW, do anyone know where I can find collections of dash app gallery with **code**?

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the columns of your data table and return your dataframe as a dict in a special form. So change these two lines in your code to make it work.

```
dt.DataTable(id='table-container', columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns.values])

return dff.to_dict('records')
```

> BTW, do anyone know where I can find collections of dash app gallery with code?

Best place with lots of examples with code is the [Dash User Guide](https://dash.plot.ly/). You can for instance find the data table [there](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable).

Comment: When I make the adjustments you suggested and try to run the code, this example also does not display a DataTable under the dropdown in the layout.

Comment: @Halee If you haven't fixed the problem yet you can open up a new question with your code.